# HTML show different div according to user language

Tags: javascript, html, display

I have a simple html page with div section. Div section contains several paragraphs `<p>`. I created separate div for every language. I want to show specific div corresponding to the user language.

I found that the language can be determined as follows

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```

And div can be made visible as follows

```
document.getElementById(language).style.display="inline;"
```

However, for some reason, it doesn't work. I assume I don't understand something fundamental in page rendering process.

I will appreciate any help with this.

Comment: If you have exception that can't set `style` of null then you need to execute  your code in `window.onload`.

Comment: what is your HTML and css?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't send all languages to the users. Instead, you should just send the correct language from the beginning.

Comment: Can you share what yo’ve tried so far? Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When modifying the style from JS you should not add any ';'. 
try

```
document.getElementById(language).style.display="inline"
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById(language).style.display="inline;"
```